# I can’t find the <modules>  about UrlRoutingModule When Create a Asp.net MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, httpmodule

I have downloaded the source code of the MVC 3 to learn How it runs .

Many people said that the MVC interceptes Http’s requests by the UrlRouting Moudle Class.

I know when you custom a HttpModule ,you need to register it like that:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="test" type="WebApplication2.MyModule1,WebApplication2"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

So  Asp.net mvc application **Web.config** file  Should be have the configuration section:

```
 <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,..." />
```

But I can't find it int the web.config file，when I create a new Asp.net MVC  application .

Someone said the IIS 7 would automatically added it .

When to IIS7 add the  configuration section?

How the IIS7 Difference it is a MVC application  or WebForm?

Comment: I really don't know what you means for "time" in your question.can you make it more clear.

Comment: I sorry  my english is poor. I will Edit  the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have a few questions in there. The `web.config` is located in the root of your start up project when you open it in Visual Studio, else if you 'explore' the application within IIS, this should take you to it also.

Not all modules are included in the web.config, some are also in the `machine.config`. This is usually in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\CONFIG`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thinks you very much! I found it!,<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"/>